# Iterator to add a counter to repeated lines in a file

Tags: string, scala, iterator

Suppose I am writing a function `Iterator[String] => Iterator[String]` to append a counter to adjacent "repeated" strings like this:

```
def foo(it: Iterator[String]): Iterator[String] = ???
foo(Iterator("a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "a", "c", "a")) // ("a", "a1", "b", "a", "a1", "a2", "c", "a")
```

I am writing a function to group all adjacent duplicates (as in run-length encoding) `groupRepeated: Iterator[String] => Iterator[List[String]]` and then I can write `foo` trivially.

Now I wonder if there is a simpler solution. What would you suggest ?

P.S. I would prefer a solution that works with `TraversableOnce` instead of `Iterator`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
it.scanLeft (("", "", 0)) { 
 case ((pref, last, count), next) if next == pref => (pref, next + (count+1), count+1) 
 case (_, next) => (next, next, 0) 
}.drop(1)
 .map(_._2)
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
def foo(it: Iterator[String]): Iterator[String] =
  new Iterator[String] {
    var currentElement: String = _
    var currentCount: Int = _

    override def hasNext: Boolean = it.hasNext

    override def next(): String = {
      val elem = it.next()

      if (elem == currentElement) {
        currentCount += 1

        s"${currentElement}${currentCount}"
      } else {
        currentElement = elem
        currentCount = 0

        elem
      }
    }
  }
```

Which works as expected:

```
foo(List("a", "a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c").iterator).toList 
// res: List[String] = List("a", "a1", "a2", "b", "a", "a1", "b", "b1", "c")
```

Comment: Thank you. It's nice but "non functional" since it uses a mutable state. I guess my solution is more "functional".

Comment: Now I think I'd prefer a function `TraversableOnce[String] => TraversableOnce[String]`. I will update the question.

Comment: @Michael What I am about to say is mostly opinion, but generally speaking, internal mutable state is ok in functional programming, because for the caller, the function is still pure. Also, in any case, if you have an **iterator** you already have a mutable reference.

Comment: I agree that iterator is already mutable in the first place. That's why I am thinking that `TraversableOnce` would be better. Anyway your solution is probably simpler than mine. Thank you for the effort !

Comment: @Michael I fixed my answer. For the generic version, you would need to dive deep into the **CanBuildFrom** stuff from the std lib _(which is still pretty "mutable")_ or maybe some state monad.

Comment: I see it. Thanks a lot.